# French name for pull-up bar rubber discs

Tags: vocabulaire, sport

I have a pull-up bar and the rubber discs that hold the bar against the wall are damaged. I can't work out what to put into google to find new ones.

I found a forum where somebody speaks about the "patins en caoutchouc" of their "barre porte" but that hasn't helped.

Answer (score 6):

« Patins en caoutchouc » does not seem to be the problem. The wrong keyword is « barre porte » that you should replace with « barre de traction ».

You can also try « patins antidérapants » instead of « patins en caoutchouc ».

I find many results in google with these keywords.